# Remember selected value on validation / Laravel 5.2

Tags: jquery, laravel, select, cookies, drop-down-menu

So I tried everything, with Laravel solutions, jquery, cookies...
Nothing has worked for me. Need value that user selected remembered, so on validation when page get's refreshed value stays the same. Wouldn't post this question if I didn't tried everything that could be find.. This is my select, all missions are listed in Mission.php and then set in @foreach. Thanks!

```
<div class="form-group">

    <label for="mission">Mission:</label>

    <select name="mission" id="mission" class="form-control" required>

        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose mission</option>

        @foreach(App\Http\Missions::all() as $mission)

            <option value="{{ $mission}}"

                    @if ($user['mission'] == $mission) selected

                    @endif>{{ $mission}}

            </option>

        @endforeach

    </select>

</div>
```

**MissionsController.php**

```
public function create()
    {
        $mission = Mission::all()->first();

        return view('mission.create', compact('mission'));
    }

public function store(MissionRequest $request)
    {
        $mission= new Mission($request->all());

        $this->missionSlug($request, $mission);

        Auth::user()->mission()->save($mission);

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: Update your controller's function also...

Comment: Are you validate from $this->validate function in controller?

Comment: Yes, it's not problem in validation, that works fine. My problem is that on validation select value is set to default, and I want value that user selected remembered.

Comment: I understood. But if you are using `$this->validate` method then you can `old()` for remember values after validation. See [https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#old-input]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found solution**. My form is partial, one form for create and update. Like this it works in both cases:

```
@foreach(App\Http\Mission::all() as $mission)

    @if (Input::old('mission') == $mission)

        <option value="{{ $mission}}" selected>

            {{ $mission}}

        </option>

    @else

        <option value="{{ $mission }}"

                @if ($user['mission'] == $mission) selected

                @endif>{{ $mission }}

        </option>

    @endif

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is ok for the create form, but you really must use the [Laravel collective Html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html), to use form builder, that is a real time savior.

Example for your update form, juste use `Form::model()`, it's magical.
and build your select like this :

```
{!! Form::select('mission', $missions) !!}
```

$missions would be called like that to work with old values :

```
$missions = Missions::lists('name', 'id');
```